# SQL condition on full name with no firstname/lastname order

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

Given a column named **fullname**, how can I filter on firstname/lastname with no order ?

In the example below in javascript, the query is not valid when searching by lastname

```js
function getQuery(searchWord){
  return `SELECT * FROM user WHERE fullname like '%${searchWord}%' `
}
// trying to search fullname "Elon Musk"
getQuery("Elon M") // okay
getQuery("Musk E") // no result
```

What is the query that allow me to find "Elon Musk" by searching by keyword "Musk Elon" ?

**NB:** columns firstname and lastname exists as well

Comment: If `fullname` contains `Elon Musk`, by which logic should `Musk E` match this value?

Comment: Does your user enter the full name or first and last name seperately

Comment: The user enter the value of "searchWord" by taping plain text in a search bar.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Which logic should be applied? What if there are more than three parts of a name (like "Joanne Kathleen Rowling")?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `FULLTEXT` search using `MATCH` `AGAINST`:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE (MATCH (fullname) AGAINST ('${searchWord} IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE'))
```

And you have to create a `FULLTEXT search index` on the column `fullname`

Or you can split your `searchWord` by space and do `LIKE '%$(searchWordPart1)%' AND LIKE '%$(searchWordPart2)%'` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i resolved the problem by using some javascript.

```js
  function getQuery(searchTerm = '') {
    // " Musk  E " => ["Musk", "E"]
    const arr = searchTerm.split(/\s+/).filter((e) => e)
    // ["Musk", "E"] => (first_name like '%Musk%' or  last_name like '%Musk%') AND (first_name like '%E%' or  last_name like '%E%')
    const conditions = arr
      .map((e) => `(first_name like '%${e}%' or  last_name like '%${e}%')`)
      .join(` AND `)
    return `use SNOW select distinct sys_id, name from dbo.sys_user where ${conditions}`
  }
```

Comment: I hope nobody enters a name containing a `'` into the search field, like `Sinéad O’Connor`, as this would result in an invalid query

Comment: Also, LIKE %% selects are very slow.